# Data retrieval is too slow in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have a view on which I apply some filters to retrieve data. This query to retrieve data is taking long time. Provided explain plan below with the query and it's access info. I have requirement to retrieve this data at a quick pace (within 30 seconds). But it is taking more than 15mins but not able to get data and timing out. Any idea how we can retrieve data quickly?

View definition as below:

```
CREATE VIEW DQ_DB.DQM_RESULT_VIEW
AS SELECT
    res.ACTIVE_FL AS ACTIVE_FL,
    res.VERSION as VERSION,
    res.rule_constituents_tx,
    nvl(ruletable.rule_desc,'N/A') AS rule_ds,
    nvl(res.effective_dt, TO_DATE('31-dec-9999','dd-mon-yyyy')) AS effective_dt,
    nvl(res.rule_id,'N/A') AS rule_id,
    res.audit_update_ts AS rule_processed_at,
    res.load_dt,
    res.vendor_group_key,
    nvl(res.vendor_entity_key,'N/A') AS vendor_entity_key,
    res.vendor_entity_producer_nm,
    (SELECT category_value_tx FROM dq_db.category_lookup_view WHERE category_nm = 'RESULT_STATUS_NB' AND category_value_cd = res.result_status_nb ) AS result,
    --catlkp.category_value_tx as result,
    res.entity_type,
    nvl(rgrp.grp_nm,'N/A') AS rule_category,
    nvl(ruletable.rule_nm,'N/A') AS rule_nm,
    feedsumm.feed_run_nm AS file_nm,
    res.application_id AS application,
    res.data_source_id AS datasource,
    res.entity_nm,
    res.rule_entity_effective_dt,
    res.result_id,
    dim.dimension_nm,
    dim.sub_dimension_nm,
    ruletable.execution_env AS execution_env,
    ruletable.ops_action AS ops_action,
    rulefunctiontable.func_nm AS rule_func_nm,
--        nvl2(res.primary_dco_sid,dq_db.get_dco_name(res.primary_dco_sid),null) AS dco_primary,
--        nvl2(res.delegate_dco_sid,dq_db.get_dco_name(res.delegate_dco_sid),null) AS dco_delegate,
    res.primary_dco_sid AS dco_primary,
    res.delegate_dco_sid AS dco_delegate,
    ruletable.data_concept_id AS data_concept_id,
    res.latest_result_fl as latest_result_fl,
    res.batch_execution_ts as batch_execution_ts
FROM
    dq_db.dqm_result res
        --LEFT OUTER JOIN dq_db.category_lookup_view catlkp on (catlkp.category_nm = 'RESULT_STATUS_NB' AND catlkp.category_value_cd = res.result_status_nb)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dq_db.feed_run_summary feedsumm ON res.vendor_group_key = feedsumm.batch_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dq_db.dqm_rule ruletable ON res.rule_id = ruletable.rule_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dq_db.dqm_rule_grp rgrp ON ruletable.rule_grp_id = rgrp.rule_grp_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dq_db.dqm_rule_function rulefunctiontable ON ruletable.func_id = rulefunctiontable.func_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dq_db.dq_dimension_view dim ON dim.dimension_id = ruletable.dimension_id
```

Explain plan of query used:

```
select * from ( select count(resultview0_.RULE_CATEGORY) as col_0_0_, 
resultview0_.RULE_CATEGORY as col_1_0_ from DQ_DB.DQM_RESULT_VIEW 
resultview0_ where (resultview0_.LATEST_RESULT_FL like :1 ) and 
resultview0_.APPLICATION=:2  and (resultview0_.DATASOURCE in (:3 )) and 
resultview0_.EFFECTIVE_DT>=:4  and resultview0_.EFFECTIVE_DT<=:5  and 
resultview0_.LOAD_DT>=:6  and resultview0_.LOAD_DT<=:7  and 
(resultview0_.RESULT in (:8  , :9 )) group by 
resultview0_.RULE_CATEGORY ) where rownum <= :10
 
Plan hash value: 722164065
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                   | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                            |                         |       |       |   746K(100)|          |       |       |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                              |                         |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                                      |                         |   592 |   155K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:24 |       |       |
|*  3 |    SORT GROUP BY STOPKEY                    |                         |   592 |   222K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:24 |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                            |                         |     1 |   102 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                           |                         |     1 |   102 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | DATA_LOOKUP_VALUE       |     1 |    51 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  7 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | PK_DATA_LOOKUP_CATEGORY |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |       |       |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | DATA_LOOKUP_CATEGORY    |     1 |    51 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  9 |     VIEW                                    | DQM_RESULT_VIEW         |   592 |   222K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:24 |       |       |
|* 10 |      FILTER                                 |                         |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|* 11 |       HASH JOIN OUTER                       |                         |   592 |   287K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:24 |       |       |
|* 12 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                         |   592 |   259K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:16 |       |       |
|  13 |         VIEW                                | index$_join$_009        |    39 |  3783 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 14 |          HASH JOIN                          |                         |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|  15 |           INDEX FAST FULL SCAN              | PK_DQM_RULE_GRP         |    39 |  3783 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  16 |           INDEX FAST FULL SCAN              | UK_DQM_RULE_GRP         |    39 |  3783 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 17 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER               |                         |   592 |   202K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:16 |       |       |
|  18 |          VIEW                               | DQ_DIMENSION_VIEW       |    28 |   224 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  19 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER                |                         |    28 |   840 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 20 |            HASH JOIN OUTER                  |                         |    28 |   616 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  21 |             INDEX FULL SCAN                 | PK_DQM_FW_DQ_DIM        |    28 |   224 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  22 |             INDEX FULL SCAN                 | PK_DQM_FW_DQ_DIM_HRCHY  |    21 |   294 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 23 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | PK_DQM_FW_DQ_DIM        |     1 |     8 |     0   (0)|          |       |       |
|* 24 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                         |   592 |   198K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:16 |       |       |
|  25 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | DQM_RULE                |   451 | 37884 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  26 |           PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR          |                         |   592 |   149K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:16 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 27 |            TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| DQM_RESULT              |   592 |   149K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:16 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 28 |             INDEX SKIP SCAN                 | IDX_PK_DQM_RESULT       |   379K|       |   373K  (1)| 01:14:42 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 29 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                 | INDEX_BATCH_ID_RUN_SMRY |   149K|  7158K|   637   (1)| 00:00:08 |       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=:10)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=:10)
   6 - filter(TO_NUMBER("VAL"."CATEGORY_VALUE_CD")=:B1)
   7 - access("CAT"."CATEGORY_ID"="VAL"."CATEGORY_ID")
   8 - filter("CAT"."CATEGORY_NM"='RESULT_STATUS_NB')
   9 - filter(("RESULTVIEW0_"."RESULT"=:8 OR "RESULTVIEW0_"."RESULT"=:9))
  10 - filter((:5>=:4 AND :7>=:6))
  11 - access("RES"."VENDOR_GROUP_KEY"="FEEDSUMM"."BATCH_ID")
  12 - access("RULETABLE"."RULE_GRP_ID"="RGRP"."RULE_GRP_ID")
  14 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  17 - access("DIM"."DIMENSION_ID"="RULETABLE"."DIMENSION_ID")
  20 - access("SUB_DIM"."SUB_DIMENSION_ID"="DIM"."DIMENSION_ID")
  23 - access("DIM1"."DIMENSION_ID"="SUB_DIM"."DIMENSION_ID")
  24 - access("RES"."RULE_ID"="RULETABLE"."RULE_ID")
  27 - filter(NVL("RES"."LATEST_RESULT_FL",U'Y') LIKE SYS_OP_C2C(:1))
  28 - access("RES"."LOAD_DT">=:6 AND "RES"."APPLICATION_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C(:2) AND "RES"."DATA_SOURCE_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C(:3) AND 
              "RES"."EFFECTIVE_DT">=:4 AND "RES"."LOAD_DT"<=:7 AND "RES"."EFFECTIVE_DT"<=:5)
       filter(("RES"."EFFECTIVE_DT">=:4 AND "RES"."DATA_SOURCE_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C(:3) AND "RES"."APPLICATION_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C(:2) 
              AND "RES"."EFFECTIVE_DT"<=:5))
  29 - filter("FEEDSUMM"."BATCH_ID" IS NOT NULL)
```

I have different indexes on DQM_RESULT table as below.

```
IDX_RULE_ID --> {RULE_ID}
IDX_PK_DQM_RESULT --> {LOAD_DT, APPLICATION_ID, DATA_SOURCE_ID, EFFECTIVE_DT, RESULT_ID}
IDX_EFF_DT_VENDOR_KEY --> {EFFECTIVE_DT, VENDOR_ENTITY_KEY}
INDEX_VENDOR_GROUP_KEY --> {VENDOR_GROUP_KEY}
IDX_EFFDT_APPDS_RUL_EID --> {LOAD_DT, APPLICATION_ID, DATA_SOURCE_ID, EFFECTIVE_DT, RULE_ID, VENDOR_ENTITY_KEY, LATEST_RESULT_FL, RESULT_ID}
```

DQM_RESULT Table is partitioned on `LOAD_DT` column and each load date contains around 15 data sources. Each data source loads around 1.5 million rows of data to each load date partition.

Comment: Did you collect statistics on all the involved tables? Do this row estimates correspond to the actual rows retrieved as per your expectation?

Comment: Yes. DBA collected stats on all tables and are up to date.

Comment: If your table is partitioned, have you checked your parallel settings? Or attempted to use the parallel hint?  Your big problem is that you have a lot of data in the `DQM_RESULT` table that is getting `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.  If you need to select the entire table every time, there isn't much you are going to be able to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the columns in this index to have the most selective columns first, or create another index with only the selective columns:

```
IDX_PK_DQM_RESULT --> {LOAD_DT, APPLICATION_ID, DATA_SOURCE_ID, EFFECTIVE_DT, RESULT_ID}
```

According to the execution plan, these operations are responsible for most of the time of the query:

```
|* 27 |            TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| DQM_RESULT              |   592 |   149K|   746K  (1)| 02:29:16 |   KEY |   KEY |
|* 28 |             INDEX SKIP SCAN                 | IDX_PK_DQM_RESULT       |   379K|       |   373K  (1)| 01:14:42 |   KEY |   KEY |
```

Skip scans require an index access for each distinct value of the initial columns, which in this case is LOAD_DT. That column might be in some sort of anti-Goldilocks zone, where it's too distinct to be useful for a skip scan, but not distinct enough to be useful for a range scan.

If the above suggestion doesn't help, you should gather more data. The explain plan only shows the *guesses* about what the optimizer will do. Use the below code to generate an execution plan, which will show both the estimates and the actual values. Edit your question and post the results and you may get better answers.

```
--Run the query with this hint to generate extra statistics.
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ ... your query here ...;

--Find the SQL_ID for your statement.
select sql_id, sql_text from gv$sql where lower(sql_text) like '%gather_plan_statistics%';

--Generate execution plan.
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID from above', format => 'allstats last'));
```